# GraphQL/Prisma Subscriptions only fire for DELETE

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions, prisma

I have set up a project using Prisma for handling the communication/storage/retrieval of data to and from the server. It is essentially the same architecture as here [example](https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-js). The only major difference is that my resolvers aren't separated into different files they are all resident in the index.js.

Now, I am trying to implement subscriptions which will catch all changes to my models. But for the life of me I cannot get the subscription to fire for anything other than DELETE actions. I have read multiple forum posts and examples but still the problem persists.

My index.js Subscription resolvers look as below:

```
Subscription: {
    userChanges: {
        subscribe: (_, args, context, info) => {
            console.log("CHECKCHECK");
            return context.prisma.subscription.user(
                { where: { mutation_in: ['CREATED'] } }, 
                info
            )
        }
    },
    taskChanges: {
        subscribe: async (_, args, context, info) => {
            return await context.prisma.subscription.task({}, info)
        }
    }
}
```

My schema.graphql looks like this:

```
# import Task, User from '../generated/prisma.graphql'
# import TaskSubscriptionPayload, UserSubscriptionPayload from '../generated/prisma.graphql'
type Query {
  task(id: ID!): Task
  tasks: [Task]!
  user(id: ID!): User
  users: [User!]
  getUserTasks(id:ID!): [Task]!
}

type Mutation {
  addTask(
    name: String!,
    priority: Float!,
    weight: Int!,
    best: Float!,
    expected: Float!,
    worst: Float!,
    calculated: Float!,
    stdDev: Float!,
    actualTime: Float,
    tags: [String!]!,
    ownedBy: ID!
  ): Task!
  updateTask(
    id: ID!,
    name: String!,
    priority: Float!,
    weight: Int!,
    best: Float!,
    expected: Float!,
    worst: Float!,
    calculated: Float!,
    stdDev: Float!,
    actualTime: Float,
    tags: [String!]!,
    ownedBy: ID!
  ): Task!
  deleteTask(id: ID!): Task!
  addNewUser(name: String!): User!
  deleteUser(id:ID!): User!
}

type Subscription {
  taskChanges: TaskSubscriptionPayload
  userChanges: UserSubscriptionPayload
}
```

I must be missing something because any/all issues I find on the Prisma forums were resolved by fixes way back in March. I suspect it may be something to do with an Async prisma binding but that is just intuition.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

A

Comment: Did you check whether the subscriptions fire on the Prisma server? That's how I'd start to debug to figure out whether this is an issue with the _application layer_ (`graphql-yoga` and `prisma-binding`) or the underlying Prisma service. You can validate that by opening a Playground for the **Prisma API** and test the `user` subscription there directly (rather than testing your `taskChanges` and `userChanges` subscriptions from the application layer).

Comment: For reference you might want to look into this example: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/tree/master/examples/subscriptions 
Also, this tutorial discusses subscriptions in detail: https://www.prisma.io/docs/tutorials/build-graphql-servers/development/build-a-realtime-graphql-server-with-subscriptions-ien5es6ok3

Comment: The console.log in my resolver does fire but only once when I first make the subscription so I know it is getting that far at the very least. When I test it in Playground by making a subscription on either the App or Prisma server I get the same result, it only fires for DELETE.

Comment: I have also tried implementing my resolvers as per the example linked by nburk above. No luck. Still the same result.

Comment: So the CREATE or UPDATE subscriptions also don't fire in the Prisma API? If that's the case, please open an issue [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?template=bug_report.md). Ideally with a minimal example to reproduce the issue (the example could then just be the Prisma API with the application layer code).

Comment: Thanks @nburk, I'll add an issue there as soon as I get a minute. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed this after much trial and error. It would seem that the initial tutorial I followed used an older version of the primsagraphql/prisma image which needed to be updated.

To fix the issue do the following:

- Edit your docker-compose.yml with a newer version (for me I upgraded from 1.12 to 1.14)

  `services:
    prisma:
      image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.14`
- Take your docker images offline then redeploy them. For me I was happy to kill them entirely using the following commands but **if you want to save your data you may want to find a different set of commands to do this**.

  `docker-compose kill
  docker-compose down
  docker-compose up -d`

Let your newly deployed Docker images warm-up a bit. Mine needed a couple of seconds to wake up for some reason :P. After that you should find your subscriptions will work again as expected.

Hope this helps others, it really took me a while to figure out that I needed to update my Docker image not my prisma npm version.

Cheers,

A